# Inheriting complex structure from a covering space (Griffiths and Harris)

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, covering-spaces

On page 16 of Griffiths and Harris' *Principles of algebraic geometry*,  they write

In general, if $\pi: M\to N$ is a topological covering space and $N$ is a complex manifold, then $\pi$ gives $M$ the structure of a complex manifold as well; if $M$ is a complex manifold and the deck transformations of $M$ are holomorphic, then $N$ inherits the structure of a complex manifold from $M$.

My question is  for the last statement does one need more assumptions on the covering $\pi: M\to N$? Or could anyone please explain to me how to construct the complex structure on $N$?

Comment: Yes, for the second statement they forgot to assume that $\pi$ is a regular covering.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Are you sure? What does "regular" even mean in this context? To begin with, $N$ is just a topological space.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval "Regular covering" is a term about covering maps of topological spaces... It means that the deck transformation group acts transitively on the fibers.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: I am using the standard algebraic topology terminology for this. People also call such covering maps "Galois" or "normal".

Comment: The terminology is justified by the image of $\pi_1(M)$ being a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(N)$ and the extension of fields of meromorphic functions being Galois.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen Thanks, that makes more sense. Assuming $\pi$ is a regular covering, I'm now getting the conclusion that  $N$ has a  complex structure that makes $\pi$ locally biholomorphic.

Comment: OK everyone, thanks for making this point clear. You are right, obviously, I just was not familiar with the term. Sorry for the mess...

Comment: Without regularity assumption the claim is simply false. Do you want to see an example? In the extreme case, the covering group is trivial while the covering is not, so the assumption on the group of deck-transformations is empty.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen The would be great. What’s your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a compact connected Riemann surface such that $\chi(X)$ is negative and divisible by $3$. Then $X$ admits an irregular topological covering $\pi: X\to Y$, where $Y$ is another Riemann surface. On the other hand,  by the dimension count, a generic Riemann surface of hyperbolic type does not admit a nontrivial holomorphic covering over any surface.  This is a counter example to the claim.

Edit. Regarding the dimension count. Let $X, Y$ be two compact Riemann surfaces of genera $g_X, g_Y$. Then every topolical covering map $p: X\to Y$ induces a holomorphic immersion $p^*: {\mathcal M}_{g_Y}\to {\mathcal M}_{g_X}$, where ${\mathcal M}$ denotes the moduli space. Here, $p^*$ sends a Riemann surface $Y\in {\mathcal M}_{g_Y}$ to the Riemann surface $X$ equipped with the pull-back of the complex structure on $Y$ via the covering $p$.

The (complex) dimensions of the respective moduli spaces are $3g_X -3 > 3g_Y-3$. Since there are only finitely many inequivalent covering maps $X\to Y$, it follows that a generic Riemann surface in ${\mathcal M}_{g_X}$ does not cover holomorphically  any other Riemann surface.

A similar argument works for surfaces of finite type.

Next, it is a nice exercise in algebraic topology to prove the following: Every compact connected oriented $X$ surface of Euler characteristic which is not a power of $2$, and hence, divisible by some prime number $q\ge 3$, admits a nontrivial degree $q$ topological covering $p: X\to Y$ whose group of covering transformations is trivial. 
Now, if you equip $X$ with a randomly chosen complex structure, then holomorphicity of the group of covering transformations of such $p: X\to Y$ is an empty condition, while $X$ does not cover any surface of smaller genus holomorphically. Hence, the claim made in Griffiths and Harris is false. They simply  forgot to require the covering to be regular.

Comment: Can you mention where you use the "divisible by 3" part? Every surface with negative Euler characteristic has a non-regular covering.

Comment: @SteveD: I want an irregular covering with trivial group of covering transformations. A degree 3 irregular covering is the easiest way to guarantee this. But any prime number $> 2$ would work just as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (and expansion of your answer).  Though it took me a while to see it, there are actually cases where $M$ is an orientable surface, $N$ is a non-orientable surface, and we have a covering $\pi: M\rightarrow N$ with trivial deck transformation group.  So this is an example where $N$ doesn't have *any* complex structure, let alone one coming from $M$.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen Thanks for your answer and example!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\pi$ is a covering, for each point  $p\in N$ there is a neighborhood $U$ such that 
$$
\pi^{-1}(U) = \cup_\alpha V_\alpha
$$
You can define a complex atlas on $N$ making $\left.\pi\right|_{V_\alpha}$ holomorphic.

If we suppose that the deck acts **transitively** and **holomorphically** on the local sheets of $\pi$, we have that the structure is well defined since every $V_\alpha$ will be biholomorphic to each other.

Comment: I had a similar idea when reading the book. Do you think one needs more assumptions to show that the complex structure is well-defined? (this is where I got stuck)

Comment: I was thinking about it and found no obstruction. In general one has to check the compatibility of the structures induced on the $U_\alpha$. This is ensured by the deck.

Comment: I think you should really write "the deck being holomorphic *and transitive*".

Comment: I'll edit It. Indeed one needs a biholomorphism between any two (local) sheets of the covering to ensure the compatibility.